Is it possible to attach metadata or parameters to Branch Quick Links
We have a few branch quick links of the form: my.app.link/readable-quick-link that we use to attribute mobile app acquisition data from different sources. We are starting to run A/B tests with StatSig and we would like to get this Branch data pass to link with Statsig. From talking with their support, we would need to pass an id that they can use to link to the exposure in the experiment such as a uuid.
Is it possible to pass information in a quick link that has already been created such as my.app.link/readable-quick-link?experiment-id=my-id, or do we have to create a branch link and embed the metadata?

You can also append this on the already created query params and then extract data from it.
If you want to have dynamic links then use the long links as suggested in the docs below
https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/creating-a-deep-link#long-links
If the data is confidential then update the link or create new links with this data inside the link which can then be extracted from the sdk.
